# Under what conditions can I interchange the order of limits for a function of two variable?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits

Suppose I have $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.   What conditions do I need to say that

$$\lim_{x \to a} \lim_{y \to b} f(x,y) = \lim_{y \to b} \lim_{x \to a} f(x,y)$$

?

What about in a more general case, by taking $X,Y$ and $Z$ topological (Hausdorff) spaces and $f$ from $X \times Y$ to $Z$ ?

Thank you

Comment: It is a little hard to say, what are you after? E.g., it would be enough if you assume that the limit $L=\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (a,b)} f(x,y)$ exists, then both of these limits are $L$.

Comment: For the function $$f ( x,\,y ) = \begin{cases}  {
x \sin {  \frac{1} {y} } + y \sin{  \frac{1}{x} } , \quad x \ne 0, \;y \ne 0, {} \\
0, \quad x=0, \;y=0  
} \end{cases} $$
  none of repeated limits $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \lim\limits_{y \to 0} f(x,y), \quad \lim\limits_{y \to 0} \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x,y)$ does not exist, but double limit 
$$ \lim\limits_{x \to 0}_{y \to 0} f(x,y)=0.$$

Comment: The above example is nice.  Just to clarify, $f(x,y)$ should be defined as $0$ if either $x=0$ or $y=0$.  Then $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}f(x,y)=0$.  But for $x\neq 0$, $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} f(x,y)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Theorem. Let $\{ F_t ; t\in T\}$ be a family of functions $F_t : X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ depending on a parameter t; let $\mathcal{B}_X$ be a base $X$ and $\mathcal{B}_{T}$ a base in $T$. If the family converges uniformly on $X$ over the base $\mathcal{B}_{T}$ to a function $F : X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and the limit $\lim_{\mathcal{B}_{T}} F_t(x)=A_t$ exists for each $t\in T$, the both repeated limits $\lim_{\mathcal{B}_{X}}(\lim_{\mathcal{B}_{T}}F_t(x))$ and $\lim_{\mathcal{B}_{T}}(\lim_{\mathcal{B}_{X}}F_t(x))$ exist and the equality

$$ 
\lim_{\mathcal{B}_{X}}(\lim_{\mathcal{B}_{T}}F_t(x))=\lim_{\mathcal{B}_{T}}(\lim_{\mathcal{B}_{X}}F_t(x))
$$
holds.

This theorem can be found in books of Zorich ([Mathematical Analysis II](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=XF8W9W-eyrgC&pg=PR3&dq=zorich%20Mathematical%20analysis%20II&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=dDbzTvSdNsWEtgeO3oXQBg&sqi=2&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=zorich%20Mathematical%20analysis%20II&f=false) p. 381).